# Visual Studio 2022 is showing *Attach* instead of *Start*

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

- I have statrted learning `ASP.Net Core Web API`.
- And just following tutorial on youtube.
- I have created new project in `Visual Studio 2022`.
- Steps I have performed to create a new project:
  Step 1:

[image: picture of step one]

Step 2:

[image: picture of step two]

Step 3:

[image: picture of step three]

After creating project: [You can see it says attach instead of start and nothing showing in solution explorer as well].

[image: Final screenshow]

Files inside project:
[image: folder view]

When I clink on `Attach`.
[image: On Attach click output]

Comment: It does not show "Start" because there is no project. So your real problem is that the project has not been created or has not been added to the solution. Can you find the *.csproj file on the disk?

Comment: Yes project is there I have seen it by going into the  respective folder.

Comment: Right click on the solution > Add existing project > select your csproj

Comment: Createing a API does not create a web site, and there is no UI or no project to run. This is not any different then say creating a simple class project. Such projects don't "run" but are to be consumed by other projects. So, create your API's or whatever, and THEN create a web based project in which you can create web pages etc., and ALSO include some API calls that you build in that other project. It not clear why you JUST creating a API project anyway, since any plain jane regular project can also have web methods that are web api calls anyway. I doubt you need nor want a API project.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Despite the name, this template actually creates a C# project. It's a "Web API" because it's a REST Web service. But it's a fully functional executable you can launch with an HTTP server you can send requests to.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, there should be ready template for weather api upon creation of this project, and I should be able to see because there is a use of swagger , which will be helpful for UI part here.

Comment: Please see I have added what files are there inside the folder

Comment: @KlausGütter please see in folder preview there is ```.csproj``` file available.

Answer (score 0):

**Troubleshoot Steps**

1. Double click the `PokemonReviewAPP.csproj` to check if it can be loaded in VS2022. If yes, it will generate the `PokemonReviewAPP.sln` file when you exit the VS2022.
2. If the project can't be loaded, please try to create a new project in other disk, like `D:/`, not in C drive. Then check the new project can be loaded or not? If yes, it means the issue related to the permission.
3. If not, it means there are some issues when you installed the VS2022. The suggestion for you is re-install the VS2022 by using the default settings.

This is the settings in my side when installing the VS2022.

[image]